# I want to import a jQuery code into the WordPress product page and functions.php file

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I can't link .js code to functions.php file .

I can't work with add_action and wp-enqueue-script. and I not know correctly where i will add function in functions.php .

my previous code :

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    wp_register_script('read-more-button', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/read-more-button.js', array('jquery'), true);
    wp_enqueue_script('read-more-button');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue-scripts',' wpb_hook_javascript',999);
```

Comment: Change `add_action('wp_enqueue-scripts',' wpb_hook_javascript',999);` to `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',' wpb_hook_javascript',999);`  You have a typo

Comment: Besides what Masivuye said, you also need to change `' wpb_hook_javascript'` to `'wpb_hook_javascript'` (remove the space at the start).